# Unable to resolve dependency for... after update android studio from 3.4 to 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

today an update for android studio has arrived from version 3.4 to 3.5. With version 3.4 everything worked correctly while at the start of version 3.5 I find errors in my project with the circleimageview library. This is what comes up

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

and this is my build.gradle file (module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.uni.project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    //circle imageview
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
}
```

I really don't know what could have gone wrong, how can I solve it? Is there a way to get back to version 3.4 since this project is important?

Comment: Try this---> Go to Refactor Menu -> Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

Comment: can you click on `Show Details` to see what it says ?

Comment: thanks for the answers I didn't try this solution, I simply re-synced the project and it worked

Comment: Simply re-syncing worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I see CircleImageView uses AndroidX [underneath](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/blob/master/circleimageview/src/main/java/de/hdodenhof/circleimageview/CircleImageView.java#L45). Try migrate you project to AndroidX

Comment: Just have tested on my project and build is successful with implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0' and AndroidX

Comment: thanks for the answers I didn't try this solution, I simply re-synced the project and it worked

Answer (score 1):

For me, the `buildType` was the problem. I removed that, did a Gradle sync, build the app and added it again.